# Java error getting sum of value in database

Tags: java

I always get error getting the sum of value from database,i used array to do this but i always get this error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException this is my method

```
public int getTotalBalance(int studentnumber){
    String sql = "SELECT * from tblPayments where StudentNumber = "+studentnumber+"";
    int ctr = 0, sum=0;
    int [] value = new int [ctr];
    try{
        Connection conn = connectToDb.ConnectDB();
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            ctr++;
            value[ctr]= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Payments"));//this is  where i get it
            sum+=value[ctr];

        }

    }catch(Exception err){
        err.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
    }


    return sum;
}
```

Comment: i would recommend to sum in query: SELECT sum(payments) from tblPayments where StudentNumber = " + studentnumber

and to use an paraemter for the studentnumber

Comment: If you only care about the value of the `Payments` column, definitely *don't* do `SELECT *`. Also, as has already been said, SQL is capable of SUMming a column for you, so take advantage of that.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the array and the `ctr` variable and just do:

```
sum += Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Payments"));
```

Even better solution is to calculate the sum in the query:

```
SELECT sum(payments) from tblPayments where StudentNumber = ? as total_sum
```

Comment: wow i got it, i worked fine. why does this simple things doesn't come in my mind

Comment: the more you practice, the faster they will come you to mind. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

0 length array is defined

```
int ctr = 0, sum=0;
int [] value = new int [ctr];
```

and now you do

```
while(rs.next()){
        ctr++;
        value[ctr]= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Payments"));
        sum+=value[ctr];
    }
```

**Solution**

Use `ArrayList` instead if you really need to store those data while you iterate

```
List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Improvement**

You should use `PreparedStatement`

You can make a single query to get sum instead of fetching full data and computing programatically

```
select sum(Payments) from tblPayments where studentNumber = ?
```

Comment: what should i do? i just want to get the sum of value from column payments.

Answer (score 0):

You create an array of size 0, ie. no elements

```
int ctr = 0, ...
int [] value = new int [ctr];
```

and then try to access the first element

```
value[ctr] = ...
```

Consider using an `ArrayList` that dynamically resizes itself and add the elements to it.

Comment: what should i do? i just want to get the sum of value from column payments.

Comment: @user3053928 Add the elements to an `List` then iterate over the elements, summing them up.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `ctr` as an empty array:

```
int ctr = 0, sum=0;
int[] value = new int [ctr];
```

And then trying to assing values to some of its elements:

```
 while(rs.next()){
      ctr++;
      value[ctr]= Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Payments"));
      sum+=value[ctr];
 }
```

Since you don't know how many results are going to be in the `ResultSet`, an array is not a good choice for a a datastructure. Instead, use one of the built-in `List` types (like `LinkedList` or `ArrayList`) that can grow on demand:

```
int ctr = 0, sum=0;
List<Integer> value = new LinkedList<Integer>();

// snipped

 while(rs.next()){
      value.add(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("Payments")));
      sum += value.get(ctr); 
      ctr++; // Note that the first element in a list is index 0.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int [] value = new int [ctr];
```

The above line is initializing the array with 0 length. You can use the getFetchSize() method of the ResultSet class to find out the number of rows returned and the initialize the array with it.